# Word that describes this quality

Tags: single-word-requests

When an entity (organization, person) does the best they can but are hindered due to outside influence or chance.

Comment: Is this two questions; hindered by influence and hindered by chance?  All endeavors suffer their practical environment and do the best they can, so I assume you mean exceptional duress and extremely bad luck.  It will be interesting to see the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps **"thwarted endeavor"**.

- *Thwarted* describes something that didn't work out, that was disappointingly unsuccessful.
- *Endeavor* is a purposeful or industrious undertaking (especially one that requires effort or boldness).

Answer (score 0):

If they are being deliberately hindered, I would probably say they were *hamstrung* or *hobbled*.

If the hindering was more incidental or accidental, then I might say they were being *weighed down* or *encumbered*.